# Amazon S3 delete subfolder and it's contents C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Suppose I have the following hierarchy in an S3 bucket.

```
Bucket
   DeptFolder
        Folder1
           Folder2
              -file1
              -file2
              -file3
```

I want to delete Folder2 and any files underneath it so it ends up looking like this...

```
Bucket
   DeptFolder
        Folder1
```

I run the following code and the delete is occurring at Folder1 not Folder2.

```
using (var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(myAccessKey,mySecretAccessKey, config))
                {

                        S3DirectoryInfo directoryToDelete = new S3DirectoryInfo(s3Client, myBucket, "DeptFolder/Folder1/Folder2");
                        directoryToDelete.Delete(true); 

                }
```

What I end up with is this...

```
Bucket
    DeptFolder
```

Can anyone tell me where I might be going wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: Does adding a forward slash after Folder2 change the result?  "DeptFolder/Folder1/Folder2/"

Comment: Adding a forward slash after Folder2 results in nothing being deleted.  I've also tried forward slash asterisk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Amazon S3 is an object storage system, not a file system.

Folders do not actually exist!

For example, you can create an object called `DeptFolder/Folder1/Folder2/foo` and the object will be created in that path, *even if the folders do not exist*! It will *appear* that the folders are there, but they are merely created as a convenience.

If the object was then deleted, **the folders would disappear too** because they don't actually exist.

I think this is what is happening to you... There are no objects in `Folder1`, so when `Folder1/Folder2` is deleted, `Folder1` also disappears because there is nothing in it to make it "appear".

**Bottom line:** Don't think of S3 as a normal file system. Don't get worried about what directories/folders exist. Just store files where you want and it will work fine. Empty folders (generally) don't exist. Don't panic!

Some people do panic, so they create empty (zero-length) files named the same as the folders, which forces the folder to appear. You can do that, but it's best to just accept the way that S3 works.

Comment: Makes great sense!  I appreciate your answer!